# Checking for strings within a dataframe

Tags: r

Within a data frame, i need to create a new column that states if certain cars are domestic or not. The first column i the data frame lists the names of the cars but that column has no name. How can i create a code that runs the names of all domestic cars to the names in the first column of the data frame and then prints yes or no in the new column? (i will create a separate list of all the cars that are domestic)
I was thinking if else statements but would not know how to reference the first column in the data frame because it has no column name. I have also tried grep() and using %in% after creating a vector of the strings of domestic manufacturers.

```
domesticmanu <- c("Duster", "Hornet", "Ford", "Valiant", "Cadillac", "Dodge")
domesticmanu %in% dataframe2
```

Comment: Could you provide sample data from `dataframe2`?

Comment: ive been using the mtcars dataset within the r package

Answer (score 1):

Using Base R:

```
mtcars[grepl(paste(domesticmanu, collapse = "|"), rownames(mtcars)),]
```

`grepl` can check multiple strings as a boolean and bring out a `T/F`. This should do the trick.